# Persisting spinner selected value

Tags: android, persistence, spinner

In the following code I am setting up a spinner, listening and detecting selections from the spinner.

The problem is I am trying to save the previously selected value so it is persistent between activity reloads, but when I reload the activity, the previously selected value is not set as the spinner value. The code is as follows :

```
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Spinner_gender);

  ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, spinnerID, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
  adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(
    new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemSelected, int selectedItemPosition, long selected){
      Editor editor = mGameSettings.edit();
      editor.putLong(GAME_PREFERENCES_GENDER, selectedItemPosition);
      editor.commit();
     }

  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

 }
  );

  //if( mGameSettings.contains(GAME_PREFERENCES_GENDER) ){
   Toast.makeText(QuizSettingsActivity.this, "Detected(again): " + spinner.getSelectedItemPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   spinner.setSelection( spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() );
  //}
```

I am using `spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()` to get the spinner selected index. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: By "Activity reloads", do you mean maintaining a saved state in between completely separate activity launches?  Or do you mean when the Activity is still in memory, and is pulled up again (like launching a separate activity from within yours, and then hitting the "back" key to return to your activity)?  Those are two seperate situations, with separate answers.

Comment: Android should automatically save the state of the spinner while your activity is still on the stack, but as Alexander mentioned it will be cleared when the activity is pushed off the stack.

Answer (score 2):

You are never reading from your `SharedPreferences`. You are writing to them (at least, I assume that is what `mGameSettings` is), but not reading from them.

> spinner.setSelection( spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() );

This is a nonsense statement. You are setting the spinner's selection to its current selection. If you want to set the spinner's selection to the value from your `SharedPreferences`, you need to read the value from the `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Perhaps you are right and spinner.setSelection( spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() ) is a lot of nonsense - or so it seems to you. I am setting the sharedpreference within the spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener() function.  Outside down at the bottom, I simply check that the sharedpreference exits and use spinner.setSelection( spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() ) to make the selected option persistant so that the next time the activity is visited, the spinner defaults to the previously selected value

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to persisting the state of spinners in Android apps in simple situations.

In my app my spinner had three values (**Normal, Important, and Urgent**). Initially, these values were stored in a `SQLite` database as strings.

My solution involved storing the spinner values instead as integers in the SQLite database and then using the following code to set the spinner value when the activity was reloaded:

```
int temp = (int) memo.getInt(memo.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MemoDbAdapter.KEY_MODE));
mModeText.setSelection(temp);
```

This allowed me pass the data from the SQLite database directly without having to work out the position of desired selection from strings stored in the database. This worked for my simple Memo application but obviously won't work if you need to store the spinner output as strings in your database.